# Ignore a field from a DTO at the Jackson deserialization time

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, deserialization

I tried to deserialize a DTO after receiving it from a request as a response, but I need to ignore a field from the DTO. The response is in JSON and I'm using Java and ObjectMapper from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` for deserialize DTO.

I can't modify this DTO to ignore a field just by using an annotation.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Share the code to get precise answer. Try annotation @JsonPropertyignore

Answer (score 0):

Please use @JsonPropertyIgnore under the hood of pojo which u dont wanted to deserialize. I,e ignore